# No puedo mostrar todos los elementos de un array, solo veo el ultimo la cantidad de veces que hay de elementos en el array

Tags: php, drupal, drupal8

Cordial saludo para todos, me encuentro tratando de solucionar un problema, al momento de mostrar en pantalla todos los elementos de un arreglo solo me muestra el ultimo y se repite la cantidad de veces que hay de elementos en el arreglo.

Con esto obtengo el arreglo

```
$column_izquiera = explode(',', $opigno_activity->get('field_palabras_izquierda')->getString());
```

El cual se ve así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => puya
    [1] =>  pelo
    [2] =>  pino
    [3] =>  pila
    [4] =>  peca
    [5] =>  loca
)
```

Y esta es la forma en la cual estoy recorriendo el arreglo para mostrar todos los elementos:

```
foreach ($column_izquiera as $words) {
      $variables['column_left'] = $words;
    }
```

Y esto es lo que obtengo:

```
loca
loca
loca
loca
loca
loca
```

Y pues sabrán que lo que necesito es obtener algo así:

```
puya
pelo
pino
pila
peca
loca
```

Por favor necesito de su ayuda muchas gracias, para mostrarlo se utiliza twig de esta manera

```
<div class="content">{{ column_left }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por supuesto que solo se guarda la última, tu bucle es exactamente eso lo que hace, guardar la última, verás:

```
foreach ($column_izquiera as $words) { // Para cada palabra en $columnn_izquiera
  $variables['column_left'] = $words; // le asigna $words...
}
```

Si analizas un poco esas líneas, verás que el resultado es este:

- Iteración 1: `$variables['column_left'] = 'puya';`
- Iteración 2: `$variables['column_left'] = 'pelo';`
- Iteración 3: `$variables['column_left'] = 'pino';`
- Iteración 4: `$variables['column_left'] = 'pila';`
- Iteración 5: `$variables['column_left'] = 'peca';`
- Iteración 6: `$variables['column_left'] = 'loca';`

Al finalizar, qué obtenemos? Pues un "array" con una única variable dentro: `$variables['column_left']`, cuyo valor será el equivalente al obtenido en la última iteración del bucle, donde has machacado el anterior valor "peca".

El problema es que en ningún momento estás *metiendo* variables en el array, si no que estás siempre *machacando* la misma variable, `'column_left'`.

Para solucionar esto, si quieres almacenar todos esos valores en `$variables['column_left']`, lo que necesitas es que eso sea un array y luego ***meter*** las demás variables en él:

```
$variables['column_left'] = []; // Declarar que el valor de eso será un array
foreach ($column_izquiera as $words) { // Para cada palabra en $columnn_izquiera
  array_push($variables['column_left'], $words); // Añade cada palabra al array
}
```

Aquí te dejo la documentación de [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) por si quieres echarle un vistazo, para cualquier duda aquí estamos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Benito-B voy a revisar